# Java how to make a custom exception?

Tags: java

I made an exception to show what's the cause of error.

below is my code

```
public class DefaultException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * DefaultException
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param cause exception
     */
    public DefaultException(Exception cause) {
        super(cause) ;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param cause error message
     */
    public DefaultException(String message) {
        super(message) ;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param cause message, exception
     */
    public DefaultException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause) ;
    }
}
```

Generating one of these constructors, specifying what's the error is successfully done.

But I want to return an error code additionally there.

It looks like...

```
public DefaultException(String message, String errorCode) {
    super(message, errorCode) ;
}
```

But `Throwable` class doens't have that constructor, so this can't be acheived this way.

How can I do this?

Comment: Create a custom field with this errorcode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the `errorCode` into a field that the `DefaultException` has and then when you catch a `DefaultException`, call getters to retrieve it.

```
public class DefaultException extends RuntimeException {

    private String errorCode;

    public DefaultException(String message, String errorCode) {
        super(message);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then when you catch it you can go like this:

```
    try {
        //something that will error
    } catch (DefaultException e) {
        String errorCode = e.getErrorCode();
        // ...
    }
```